# Changing the alignment of comments when using algorithmics

Tags: algorithmicx

When using comments in the algorithmicx package like in the code below, the comment is aligned at the right. How do I change that? I'd like the comment to appear next to the code, separated by a tab.

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State $var$ \Comment{comment about var}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can re-define how the comment is formatted, perhaps something like this:

```
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hskip2em$\triangleright$ #1}
```